# UITableViewCells won't load index is out of range

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to load some data from CloudKit to populate a tableview with custom cells and I am having difficulty getting the data to appear.

When I define the number of rows as the count of the CKRecord array the tableview shows up, but with nothing loaded into them. They are just spaced out correctly for the images to be in there. Also, when I set breakpoints at `let record = matches[indexPath.row]` it won't trigger.

However, if I change the `return matches.count` to an actual number, the project crashes at `let record = matches[indexPath.row]`
 with the error that the index is out of range. I want to keep the number of rows as the count for the record array, but that is the only change that will actually execute the override function that calls the tableview cell.

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return matches.count
    }


     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Card", for: indexPath) as! MatchTableViewCell

        let record = matches[indexPath.row]

        if let img = record.value(forKey: "Picture") as? CKAsset {
        cell.profileimg.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: img.fileURL.path)

        }

        return cell
    }
```

Any advice is appreciated

Update- here is where I load the model

```
 func loadModel() {

        let totalMatch = (defaults.object(forKey: "passedmatch") as! [String] )

        let predicateMatch = NSPredicate(format: "not (UserID IN %@)", totalMatch )


        ProfilesbyLocation = defaults.object(forKey: "Location") as! String

        let query = CKQuery(recordType: ProfilesbyLocation , predicate: predicateMatch )

        publicData.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil,completionHandler: ({results, error in

            print("loading")

            if (error != nil) {
                let nsError = error! as NSError
                print(nsError.localizedDescription)
                print ("error")

            } else {
                if results!.count > 0 {
                        DispatchQueue.main.async() {

                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                        self.refresh.endRefreshing()

                        print("refreshed")
                       }

                }
            }
            }
            )
        )}
```

Comment: And there's no possibility that `matches` is being changed somehow in between the calls to `numberOfRowsInSection` and `cellForRowAt`?

Comment: That array loads at `viewdidload` asynchronously so I'm not sure how it could change after that

Comment: *A*synchronously? So it *could* be changed by another thread while the main thread is attempting to read from it?

Comment: changed it to sync and it crashes the same, so unless its changing in another way that doesn't seem to be the issue.

Comment: Could your `matches` array contain `nil`s?

Comment: I just went through and checked, they are all good. The records do contain an asset (picture) as well as 3 other strings, however I am not allocating those strings to anything in the cell. That shouldn't effect anything, correct?

Comment: Can you show us what the code looks like where you are loading the `matches` array?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are not calling

```
tableview.reloadData()
```

after your asynchronous data comes in. Leave `numberOfRowsInSection` as it is and make sure when your network request comes back you are reloading. That should do it.

Comment: I added that and I still am getting the same error. I tried it in both my loading data function and in the override function.

Answer (score 0):

If you received your data from background thread(or queue), please make sure when you update your UI elements under the **main thread**(or queue). Try this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem.

First, disconnect the Delegate/DataSource of the TableView from the Interface Builder [refer this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnYn3.png). When you have finally prepared your data that is **matches array** then add this.

```
`DispatchQueue.main.async {
    tableView.dataSource = self 
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.reloadData
}`
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `matches` is incorrect. Before you call `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int)`
, you should check your `matches`.

If you are still not sure about that. You can init your `matches` with string literals and have a try.